# Increasing the length of frame ticks

Tags: plotting, ticks

I know that I can manually adjust the frame tick length using `FrameTickStyle`. However, is there a way to globally increase the tick length?

Comment: What algorithm do you have in mind for increasing the tick length? How would it handle the production of major and minor ticks? `FrameTicks` does accept a generating function on righthand side of it rule. I think the best you can do is write a generating function includes code for producing  ticks long enough to satisfy you.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the internal function `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` (it takes the option `TicksLength`):

```
tickFunc = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, 
 TicksLength -> {.05, .02}][##] &;

Plot[
   x^2,
   {x, 0, 5},
   Axes -> False,
   Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{tickFunc , Automatic}, {tickFunc , Automatic}}
 ]
```

[image]

Alternatively, to have the setting apply to all subsequent calls to `Plot`, you can set the option `TicksLength` globally:

```
SetOptions[Charting`ScaledTicks, TicksLength -> {.05, .02}];
```

and use the setting `{{All, Automatic}, {All, Automatic}}` for `FrameTicks`:

```
Plot[
  x^2,
  {x, 0, 5},
  Axes -> False,
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{All, Automatic},{All, Automatic}}
]
```

> same picture

```
Plot[
  Sin[x],
  {x, 0, 5},
  Axes -> False,
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{All, Automatic},{All, Automatic}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks kglr, this is exactly what I am looking for. However, where can I find documentation for functions such as `Charting`ScaledTicks`??

Comment: @baker,  ``Charting`ScaledTicks`` is not documented. You can use ``Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]; PrintDefinitions[Charting`ScaledTicks]`` to see its definition.

Comment: @kglr this comment is more valuable than I can express!!! I feel there should be a general answer to show the usage of this function, even if it is undocumented (because it is undocumented!).

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I'm a little amazed that plot ticks didn't get a little bit of TLC during this last big update. I'm a little hopeful that it's on their list, but I'm not going to hold my breath.

The best way I've found to do this *somewhat* easily, is to download and install one of Mark Caprio's packages, either `SciDraw` or `CustomTicks`(http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5599/). Once installed in the directory appropriate for your system (the guide provides instructions), you can do something like this:

```
<<CustomTicks`
SetOptions[LinTicks, TickLengthScale -> 2];
Plot[
  x^2,
  {x, 0, 5},
  Axes -> False,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{LinTicks, StripTickLabels[LinTicks]}, 
                 {LinTicks, StripTickLabels[LinTicks]}}
]
```

[image: Plot of x^2 with longer ticks.]

I admit that this requires a bit of extra work the first time, but I set it up once back when I first got Mathematica 10, and haven't had to worry about it since. Plus, `CustomTicks` has a number of other useful features for ticks such as easily switching from inner ticks to outer ticks.

The other approach is to create your own function for generating ticks. It works, but it's cumbersome, and there are often unforeseen edge cases (well, there are for me, but perhaps others have better foresight).

```
ticks[min_, max_, stepsz_, majdivs_, baselength_, 
  insideticks_?BooleanQ, labels_?BooleanQ] := 
    Table[
      {i, If[Mod[i - min, majdivs] == 0 \[And] labels, ToString[Round@i], ""],     
        If[insideticks, #, Reverse[#]] &[{If[Mod[i - min, majdivs] == 0, 2 
          baselength, baselength], 0}]}, 
      {i, min, max, stepsz}
    ]

Plot[
  x^2,
  {x, 0, 10},
  Axes -> False,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
                 {ticks[1, 9, 0.2, 2, 0.02, True, True], 
                  ticks[1, 9, 2/10, 2, 0.02, True, False]}}
]
```

[image: Plot of x^2 using my own tick generating function.]